# What possibly a Mac prohibit remote connection?

Tags: vpn, macos, netcat

With my company Mac, I can't connect to one of my company's server:ppppp.

The problem is all my colleagues can connect to the server:ppppp.

All environments are same.

- Connect VPN

  - all works including mine that I can connect to Atlassian products such as JIRA, Confluence.
- Connect to the server:ppppp

  - I am the only one that fails.
  - Others remained Monterey, but one of them also upgrades to the Ventura.

```
$ nc -zvv server port
Warning: Inverse name lookup failed for `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn'
server [nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn] ppppp: Operation timed out
Total received bytes: 0
Total sent bytes: 0
```

What possibly a Mac machine (Ventura) prohibits remote connection?
Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you have private relay turned on?

Comment: @I0_ol Thank you for your comment. What is a *private relay*? How can I check any on?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Private relay is feature is newer versions of Mac OS that essentially acts like a VPN. I found that with private relay turned on, I was unable to get other 3rd party VPN's to connect. Once private relay was turned off I was able to connect again. You'll find it in system settings under iCloud settings.